# Android ListView No Data Found vs. No Search Result Found

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts, empty-list

I am implementing a ContactList screen. If there is no Contact at beginning, I will show an empty experience - something like "No Contact Found, Click + button to add now". If there are contacts, just display all the contacts. Above the contact list, I have a search bar. When you enter keyword, it will do the search. And when there is no result found, it will just show empty list.

SO, I have a listView and an empty view if the list has no data. It works fine for Empty Data. However, when no result found, it still shows the empty view.

```
View emptyView = rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Is there a way of differentiating these two?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very simple.
You have to just create another new View for that "NO RESULTS FOUND".
Something like this one:

```
 View noResultsFoundView = rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.no_results_found_view);
 mListView.setEmptyView(noResultsFoundView);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a if statement if there is data in your list view set visibility to hide